# Origin to geometry by default

Tags: customization

Is there a way (can't find in preferences) to set the origin to geometry by default to imported objects? Very time consuming to set each time manually, I'm working a lot with svg's...

Comment: Imported objects origins are determined by the original origin in the source application, or worst case scenario by the importer addon's discretion, not some arbitrary global preference. SVG files don't have a concept of "Object Origins" for the most part, with the possible exception of instances or groups. That being said you can batch set origins-to-geometry on a bunch of objects at once. It's a one step process, and shouldn't be that time consuming.

Comment: I'm importing a lot of svg's during the work' not all together, this one step process multiply by a lot of times it's time consuming... anyway, thnx for answering! maybe a way to set the object in inkscape to be imported to blender with right origin?

Comment: One possibility would be to manually edit the SVG import python script to run the operator that changes object origins for each imported curve at the end, though that may is well above my skill level.

Answer (score 1):

I took the python template Simple Operator and inserted the operator that sets the origin to geometry (found when pressing the button and looking in the Info window). I then selected a few objects and set them up with origins at the cursor so I could test, and ran the script. With all of them selected, I pressed the space bar and chose "Origin to Geometry All", the name of the new operator.

Maybe it could help, though it isn't as clean as it could be with some work.

edit: turns out you don't need all that since the operator works on multiple objects at once already. Simply select all the objects you need to change origins to geometry and then press 'Origin to Geometry' in the tool bar. So if you have imported 30 objects and need to fix their origins, select all and then press the operator.

Comment: thnx, for answering. Yes' of cours I know that I can change them all together' the problem that I importing a lot of svg one by one' during all the animation work' not all together' and each time I have to scale them and put the origin to geometry' it's just so not user friendly' It's not  a smooth, professional user experience...

Comment: Maybe I can take a look at the code that is in the importer script - might be easy to just add the operator there then.

Comment: It would be great to have an option like that!